# Multicast propagation with daisy chained multi NIC card PCs

Tags: zeromq, multicast

Here is the topology under discussion:

```
         NIC0                       NIC0                    NIC0
          |                          |                       |
    +-----+-----+             +------+-----+          +------+------+
---NIC1       NIC2---------NIC1            NIC2-----NIC1          NIC2---- . .
    +----PC1----+             +----PC2-----+          +-----PC3-----+
```

I have stack of PC Boxes each having multiple (3) Nic Cards, one to interface with outside world, and others to be used to daisy chain for communication among themselves.

Q(1) Can someone suggest if I can somehow control "multicast traffic" on daisy chained systems without letting that mixed with traffic coming from NIC0(diagram below) Cards? 
I am running Linux kernel on each boxes. I can give multicast address in the interface name, but my guess is that it would not guarantee the mixing of traffic if the NIC0 traffic also has same multicast IP, so, is ACL a answer?

Q(2) My application needs subscribe-notify setup, and that's why I need multicast. There are options such as using 0MQ that also use TCP based multicast(PGM). Will that protect me here somehow?

Comment: UDP routing is based on the port not the IP address under Linux so you can use the same multicast group just ensure a different port.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would daisy chain these computers.  Before going any further, you should connect these machines with a switch.

Really, though, I don't understand what your questions is...